# ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects python

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = df1.loc[df1['CUST_ACCT_KEY'] != df2['CUST_ACCT_KEY']]
```

When I execute the above command, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

What am I doing wrong?*

The dtypes of both the column are `int64`.

Comment: The indexed of df1 and df1 are both resetted before performing the action

Answer (score 8):

`Pandas` does almost all of its operations with intrinsic data alignment, meaning it uses indexes to compare, and perform operations.

You could avoid this error by converting one of the series to a `numpy` array using `.values`:

```
df = df1.loc[df1['CUST_ACCT_KEY'] != df2['CUST_ACCT_KEY']].values
```

However, you are comparing row to row with no index alignment.

MCVE:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,10), index=np.arange(1,10),columns=['A'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(11,20), index=np.arange(11,20),columns=['B'])

df1['A'] != df2['B']
```

Output:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Change to numpy array:

```
df1['A'] != df2['B'].values
```

Output:

```
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
8    True
9    True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: The indexes of both df1 and df2 were resetted before I perfomed the task. I also tried numpy.where, but yielded the same result

Comment: Can you post some data along with code in the question.

Comment: I made use of my unique indexes to filter the data. Didn't need to reset the data - df.drop(df_subset.index)