# >> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```py
df['sign'] = np.where(dA['purple'] >=dd['ve'], 'positive', 'negative')
```

I got this error: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Comment: Is your question what "identically-labeled" means?

Comment: Do `all(df.index == dd.index)`. If the answer is `False`, [that's the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067449/valueerror-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-series-objects-python).

Comment: df and dd is a  data frame contains other columnes

Comment: my question is how to colomnes with diferent labeld

Comment: Please consider adding a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.  This is the most sure-fire way to get an useful answer.

Comment: "identically-labeled" means that the two dataframes should have the same index. Otherwise, pandas wouldn't know how to compare them (which row of `df` corresponds to which row of `dd`). The columns don't need to be the same. See the answer in the link from my previous comment.

Comment: The error is probably caused by: `dA['purple'] >=dd['ve']`.  `dA` and `dd` must be dataframes with different row indices.  This comparison is not allowed (by `pandas`)